# How to read the rest of a line after a specific string

Tags: c++, string

Please tell me how to write a function that checks every row in a file, and if it encounters a certain string (eg "set cookie"), it will output the rest of that line.

Comment: "do not tell me how"So... what SHOULD we tell you?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post some code so we can see what problems you have encountered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `strstr`. First, line by line, read into a variable (use `cin.getline`), then check the given line using [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/). If the output of `strstr` is **not** `NULL`, then process the line as you see fit.

Comment: strstr?  This is the C++ tag here.  We use streams.  Also, prefer std::getline to std::cin::getline.  They're different..

Comment: Fine, use `string::find` then.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: @slugonamission, [why cplsuplus.com is bad](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com)